# How to show custom alert on top of all activities in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view

I am doing an AsyncTask to call an API call in my application. And showing the API response as an Alert. I have written that API calls on home screen activity and showed that alert on top of the home screen. But if I moved from that activity to another activity, that alert visible once I back to the home screen. Not showing on top of all activities. So my requirement is to show that alert on top of all activities once that API is successful.

```
private void AlertSubmitted(String message) {
      
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlayout, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

        TextView btn_ok = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        TextView txt_dia = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txt_dia);

        txt_dia.setText(message);

        if(subAlertDialog != null && subAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
            return;
        }
        subAlertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

        subAlertDialog.show();
        btn_ok.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                dbManager.deleteData();
                text.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                subAlertDialog.dismiss();
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line with your existing line of alert dialog code

```
subAlertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```